# Issue with viewModel and TextField

Tags: swiftui

I'm not sure whether it's a SwiftUI bug or it's my fault:

When I type some text in a `TextField` and press the return button on my keyboard (in order to hide my keyboard), the typed text is removed and the `TextField` is empty again. I've tried this solution on different simulators and on a real device as well. The issue appears every time. I'm using iOS 14.3, Xcode 12.4

`TextField` view:

```
struct CreateNewCard: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: CreateNewCardViewModel
    var body: some View {
        TextField("placeholder...", text: $viewModel.definition)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class CreateNewCardViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var definition: String = "" 
}
```

Main View:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var showNew = false

    var body: some View {
    Button(action: { showNew = true }, label: { Text("Create") })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showNew, content: {
            CreateNewCard(viewModel: CreateNewCardViewModel())
        })
    }
}
```

@SwiftPunk: Here is my second question:

Let's say my view model has an additional parameter (`id`):

```
class CreateNewCardViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var id: Int
    @Published var definition: String = "" 
}
```

This parameter needs to be passed when I create the view to my viewModel. For this example let's say we iterate over some elements that have the id:

```
struct MainView: View {
@State var showNew = false

var body: some View {
ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { index in // <<<---- this represents the id
    Button(action: { showNew = true }, label: { Text("Create") })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showNew, content: {
            // now I have to pass the id, but this 
            // is the same problem as before 
            // because now I create every time a new viewModel, right?
            CreateNewCard(viewModel: CreateNewCardViewModel(id: index))  
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here, that you did not create a StateObject in main View, and every time you pressed the key on keyboard you created a new model which it was empty as default!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showNew = false
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: CreateNewCardViewModel = CreateNewCardViewModel()  // <<: Here

    var body: some View {
    Button(action: { showNew = true }, label: { Text("Create") })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showNew, content: {
            CreateNewCard(viewModel: viewModel)
        })
    }
}
```

---

```
struct CreateNewCard: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: CreateNewCardViewModel

    var body: some View {

        TextField("placeholder...", text: $viewModel.definition)
            .foregroundColor(.black)

    }
}
```

---

```
class CreateNewCardViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var definition: String = ""
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. This makes sense... but I'm wondering how can I solve my problem if I need to create a viewModel for an individual element? Let's say I have a `List` with some elements and for each element I need a specific viewModel that I have to pass as a parameter (e.g. `viewModel(elem: element1)` )? A "fixed" StateObject is not possible anymore, right?

Comment: you are welcome, I have problem to understand and read your code, can you make a question and show code there and we work there together there?

Comment: I've added my second question. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Erik: Thanks for adding your question, but I wanted to tell you make a new question, we cannot have 2 question in one Post, and maybe your question be deleted or closed because of that, so please, edit this question to first one, and make new question for second one, I come to the new question.