# How can I have multiple instance of a Class/Model in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

The [first part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66707506/issue-with-viewmodel-and-textfield) of question is answered. Let's elaborate this example to:

`TextField` view:

```
struct CreateNewCard: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: CreateNewCardViewModel
    var body: some View {
        TextField("placeholder...", text: $viewModel.definition)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class CreateNewCardViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var id: Int
    @Published var definition: String = "" 
}
```

Main View:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var showNew = false

    var body: some View {
    ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { index in // <<<---- this represents the id
    Button(action: { showNew = true }, label: { Text("Create") })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showNew, content: {
            // now I have to pass the id, but this 
            // leads to that I create a new viewModel every time, right?
            CreateNewCard(viewModel: CreateNewCardViewModel(id: index))  
        })
    }
}
```

My problem is now that when I type something into the `TextField` and press the return button on the keyboard the text is removed.

Comment: I think you have wrong plan in your code, do you want create multiple instance of that class? because in your ForEach you are going create 10 deferent instance  of CreateNewCardViewModel. do you want that?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Each View should have a viewModel that handles a a specific element (identified by the `id` for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most strange way of coding that i seen, how ever I managed to make it work:

*I would like say that you can use it as leaning and testing, but not good plan for real app, How ever it was interesting to me to make it working.*

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        MainView()
    }
}
```

---

```
class CreateNewCardViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable, Equatable {

    init(_ id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
    
    @Published var id: Int
    @Published var definition: String = ""
    @Published var show = false
    
    static func == (lhs: CreateNewCardViewModel, rhs: CreateNewCardViewModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}


let arrayOfModel: [CreateNewCardViewModel] = [ CreateNewCardViewModel(0), CreateNewCardViewModel(1), CreateNewCardViewModel(2),
                                               CreateNewCardViewModel(3), CreateNewCardViewModel(4), CreateNewCardViewModel(5),
                                               CreateNewCardViewModel(6), CreateNewCardViewModel(7), CreateNewCardViewModel(8),
                                               CreateNewCardViewModel(9) ]
```

---

```
struct ReadModelView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: CreateNewCardViewModel
    
    var body: some View {

            TextField("placeholder...", text: $viewModel.definition)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        
    }
}
```

---

```
struct MainView: View {

    @State private var arrayOfModelState = arrayOfModel
    @State private var showModel: Int?
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        

        VStack {
            
            ForEach(Array(arrayOfModelState.enumerated()), id:\.element.id) { (index, item) in
                
                Button(action: { showModel = index; isPresented = true  }, label: { Text("Show Model " + item.id.description) }).padding()

            }

            if let unwrappedValue: Int = showModel {
                
                Color.clear
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: { ReadModelView(viewModel: arrayOfModelState[unwrappedValue]) })
  
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I've realized that I have a big misunderstanding of the MVVM pattern...